# Opencv dnn module inference does not use GPU on Jetson TX2 for SSD mobilenet

Tags: opencv, dotnetnuke

I m using the following to detect objects using SSD mobilenet (CAffe) on Jetson TX2 with opencv3.4.1 and Cuda 9.0

```
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(frame, (300, 300)), 0.007843, (300, 300), 127.5)
net.setInput(blob)
detections = net.forward()
```

The tegrastats show no GPU usage at all. 
All the cores of the CPU are utilized properly, however GPU utilisation is zero.

How can I enable GPU usage on the Jetson for faster FPS on videos ?

Thanks

Comment: opencv's DNN does not use cuda, afaik. It uses Halide? Maybe better use tensorRT in your application for inference on the jetson.

Comment: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/1010

Comment: Have you tried to use OpenCL? https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d0f/group__dnn.html#gga709af7692ba29788182cf573531b0ff5a45f8ea53f004e52665078a88167c7c08

Comment: I guess Opencl is not supported on Jetson TX2 :( .. Can someone please confirm.    I am stuck... Opencv dnn module does not support CUDA and I cant even use OpenCL .. Any other way forward ?

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV DNN can use only Intel GPU to OpenCL inference. That check was placed in the OpenCV source code.

Comment: That's not right at this moment. Check a PR https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/12565. If GPU supports OpenCL - OpenCV's dnn can use OpenCL backend.